# Webdriver - which proxy to use to log all requests urls

Tags: ruby, selenium, proxy, webdriver

I use Firefox driver. I'd want to proxy traffic and log urls of all requests that pass through proxy.

The requirements for proxy are:

- It shouldn't modify traffic
- I should be able to modify location where log is saved programmatically
- I should be able to clear log at any moment
- Log shouldn't be shared across multiple Webdriver threads

I thought about Browsermob proxy but HAR seems to be too heavy solution for logging just request urls. Also I don't know if Browsermob proxy's HAR is able to handle tens of thousands of entries.

Comment: I use Browsermob as the result and it seems good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try [proxy](https://www.npmjs.org/package/proxy) written in node. super simple.